# How to show tick marks in Xamarin forms slider control

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin forms Slider control in portable project.This is correctly showing minimum, maximum values.But i want to show **tick marks** in this control so that user can know number of steps.

This solutions supports Android as well as ios.
Below is the control I am using:-

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Maximum="{Binding Maximum}"
                    Minimum="{Binding Minimum}" />
```

Can someone help me with links or code snippets ?

Answer (score 1):

The slider which comes with Xamarin.Forms doesn't have any tick marks.
Basically you have three options:

1) Make a custom Xamarin Forms View with a grid that holds the slider and several BoxViews forming your tick marks and expose the needed values as BindableProperties. 
Pro: Can be done quite fast, no need for custom renderers
Con: Not the most elegant solution

2) Make a custom renderer, rendering the slider the way you want it.
Pro: Better solution, since you only need to add your custom slider to the view
Con: You need to create a custom renderer for each target platform handling the drawing of the tick marks

3) Look for a suitable component or a nuGet Package that contains a slider suitable for your needs

Comment: Hi @Markus,
I am trying by adding custom renderer for android. But not able to assign value/shape to tickmark. Below is my code:-
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (this.Control != null)
            {
                var slider = (MySlider)this.Element;    
                //this.Control.TickMark -- how to add ?    
            }
        }       
 }

Comment: ok  I got to set TickMark using below line:-
this.Control.TickMark = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
But this doesn't show marks for all steps. I want to show small vertical marks on every step so that user can get a feel of how many steps are present and in how much duration.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally ended with this solution for Android:-

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.Control != null)
            {
                var slider = (MySlider)this.Element;

                this.Control.TickMark = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Icon);//works by setting whole slider image
                //this.Control.SetThumb(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Icon));//works by setting thumbnail movable image

                Control.Max = (int)(slider.Maximum - slider.Minimum);//shows RHS value plus one
                Control.Progress = (int)slider.Value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for xamarin forms slider with ticks

https://xamarinexperience.blogspot.com/2019/03/how-to-add-tick-marks-on-sliders-in.html